# How to run multiple command in one line and some commands in background at the same time?

Tags: command-line, background-process

I know I can use `&` at the end of a command to make it run in background and `&&` to connect multiple commands at the same line. However, when I use them together it seems not work. Below is an example.

```
json-server --watch db.json & && python -m http.server 7777
```

The error message is:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
```

Is it possible to make them work together? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you want this

```
json-server --watch db.json & python -m http.server 7777
```

The `&&` is not to connect multiple commands at the same line, that is `;`. The `&&` is a logical AND. You can't use an AND  if you don't wait for the command to exit.